# unable to unmount disk to reset fusion

Tags: recovery

I have a 2012 Macbook pro with a split fusion drive.
I tried: `diskutil resetFusion`

```
couldn't unmount the SSD  
couldn't unmount the HDD  
fails with error 69877 couldn't open device
```

I am in terminal in recovery mode.

`diskutil unmountDisk` also fails

`diskutil cs list` says:

```
no CoreStorage logical volume groups found
```

If I leave terminal and enter recover disk utility it just hangs on the wheel trying to load drives.

`diskutil list`: (continues to disk image 22)

[image: diskutil list]

Comment: The picture is too low quality to make out any of the text. Please upload the image at a higher resolution.

Comment: In Recovery Mode you can open a second terminal (cmd+n) then inside the command `/Applications/Safari.app/Contents/MacOS/safari` open Safari and can help you to connect at the forum and copy/paste in text mode the results of command (from an other terminal) : `diskutil list internal`

Comment: I think you might have to create a bootable installer on a flash drive and boot that. In recovery mode you should then be able to reset the internal fusion drive as it won’t be in use.